# Docker containers "bad gateway" error using container name as DNS name (with ip it works)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns

**Abstract: I can connect a docker container to another container (that's in a docker-compose file) using a (custom) docker network, only with IP address. Using the container name as DNS results in "Bad gateway" error.**

I am trying to make Grafana (as a docker-compose) work with a Prometheus (as a docker container). I connected the prometheus container to the network defined by the Grafana docker compose. This way, I can use the prometheus server as a datasource for Grafana, as long as I am using it's IP address. How can I make it work using DNS names? Using the container name as a DNS name results in a "Bad Gateway" error.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  k6:
  grafana:

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:1.8
    networks:
      - k6
      - grafana
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=k6

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    networks:
      - grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_BASIC_ENABLED=false
    volumes:
      - ./grafana:/etc/grafana/provisioning/

  k6:
    image: loadimpact/k6:latest
    networks:
      - k6
    ports:
      - "6565:6565"
    environment:
      - K6_OUT=influxdb=http://influxdb:8086/k6
    volumes:
      - ./samples:/scripts
```

Command for prometheus container:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --network k6_grafana -v C:\xy\QA\K6\prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus
```

docker network inspect k6_grafana

```
[
    {
        "Name": "k6_grafana",
        "Id": "15de38f97d93a0c697de4bfdc4fe0f441bcacde9fd43f5b9d1608908bb26c954",
        "Created": "2021-10-26T09:45:17.6385164Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.27.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "37e0a02a2c7f73b2be78623a4d239b86eb2e2a1a14e8b3416d472de2a719d701": {
                "Name": "k6_grafana_1",
                "EndpointID": "f0bf0f4844775c3fa6ce6758e2e4413ff3de40e5d6b93158e5668ebe4661f6a5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6efce075e766ce581e134947ef2067d0b3ae433476c850e02768b624c672da0f": {
                "Name": "practical_lalande",
                "EndpointID": "363c42b1c5194e95d4469f7c474973ba8b21f8fe2573fb22f3fac76c5ab8a1af",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d075b1aa33452c38e0340e4a10997be3665377a43a961e99ecab580af22dfe02": {
                "Name": "k6_influxdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "4716f96665f4f93acd3cc087d1cad1048ee035062d950fddfe9d3e176a34bcbf",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "grafana",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "k6",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.28.5"
        }
    }
]
```

So using http://172.27.0.4:9090 to connect is ok! But using http://practical_lalande:9090 to connect (or any other name), is not working!

According to the docker documentation, this should work:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between
> containers.
>
> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by
> IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered
> legacy. **On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve
> each other by name or alias.**

Comment: As I'm reading it, you have 3 networks: k6, grafana and k6_grafana. You can only specify one network on `docker run`. After it's started, you can connect it to more using `docker network connect`.

Comment: I have two networks: k6_k6, k6_grafana (both networks in the compose file are prefixed by "k6_" the folder name which I'm using. But I think it's beside the point, as from the "k6_grafana" network inspect, you can see, that both containers are connected to the same network (other docker network configs shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that this doesn't work with docker generated names. The "practical_lalande" container name was generated by docker. Creating a container with a custom name with the "--name" option solves the problem.